# SQL Developer errors: ORA-06512 and ORA-04088

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-06512, ora-04088

```
create or replace
TRIGGER TR_T_PR_FARMACO
BEFORE INSERT ON T_PR_DIZ_FARMACO
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

IF LENGTH(:new.T_PR_DIZ_FARMACO_MINSAN) < 9 THEN RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20013,'La lunghezza del MINSAN deve essere di 9 cifre');
END IF;
END TR_T_PR_FARMACO;
```

When i try to insert in T_PR_DIZ_FARMACO wrongly, the trigger works, but with these errors:

> Errore durante il salvataggio delle modifiche nella tabella "BMF"."T_PR_DIZ_FARMACO":
>   Riga 2: ORA-20013: La lunghezza del MINSAN deve essere di 9 cifre
>   ORA-06512: a "BMF.TR_T_PR_FARMACO", line 8
>   ORA-04088: errore durante esecuzione del trigger 'BMF.TR_T_PR_FARMACO'
>   ORA-06512: a line 1

(Translated)

> Error saving changes in table "BMF". "T_PR_DIZ_FARMACO":
>   Line 2: ORA-20013: The length of the MINSAN must be 9 digits
>   ORA-06512: to "BMF.TR_T_PR_FARMACO", line 8
>   ORA-04088: error while executing the trigger 'BMF.TR_T_PR_FARMACO'
>   ORA-06512: a line 1

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: So... it's working well. Is there any problem with it?

Comment: It is simply working as expected ...

Comment: Why are you using a trigger instead of a check constraint?

Comment: Those are database errors, not SQL Developer errors.

Comment: If the value of T_PR_DIZ_FARMACO_MINSAN is lower than 9, your trigger says this error will occur. I think, you need a cup of coffee :)